# Nautilus does not start

Tags: nautilus

When trying to open `nautilus` (from the [Launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-launcher-intro.html) or from the [Dash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html) pressing on [Files](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/files.html)), it does not open, and the desktop aren't responding.

The output of `nautilus -q` **(without sudo)**:

```
(nautilus:12039): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:12039): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached
(nautilus:12039): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:12039): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:12039): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

If i use `gksu nautilus` it opens but with an error:

```
(nautilus:18320): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
```

Currently fixing this issue by restart my PC or by restart `nautilus`:

```
sudo killall nautilus && (nautilus &)
```

But is just a temporary fix.

---

This bug has been reported here: 
[Bug report on Nautilus in 16.04.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1569970)

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` for Nautilus?

Comment: You right. i changed it

Comment: Since you removed `sudo` from your post now, do you get the same results with `nautilus -q` (without `sudo`)? (Contact me in chat if you think this is going to lead to extended discussion unsuitable for the comment section.)

Comment: If you always used `sudo`, that would explain the problem of its not launching. Please [edit] your question and clarify whether this only happens when using `sudo`. Also explain how you try to open nautilus and when you are doing it. Is it after rebooting or after waking up from suspend?

Comment: i am not using `sudo` to open `nautilus`. i am not suspend my PC, after rebooting `nautilus` always working properly, it happens once or several times a day.

Comment: be advanced, use nemo. anutilus is awork in progress and alpha software in my opinion. Your choice to use or not to use it as a filemanager.