# Nautilus does not start: .cache/tracker/meta.db not found

Tags: nautilus

Nautilius does not start. I have ubuntu 20.04. Recently, I installed it, after that I changed the default home for the home that I had in ubuntu 18.04.

In terminal I wrote:

```
nautilus $HOME
```

and I get:

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:8908): Tracker-WARNING **: 07:11:21.529: Falling back to bus backend, the direct backend failed to initialize: Could not find database file:'/home/alejo/.cache/tracker/meta.db'.
```

I looked at: [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844106/nautilus-does-not-start) and is not related to my question.

Any suggestion?

Comment: 18.04, 19.10 and 20.04 are supported, all of which have different nautilus versions. It is therefore very important you mention the version you use.

Comment: @vanadium thank you, the version is 20.04

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information there. I do not think that the terminal message will point to the issue, because that is just a warning message.

Comment: @vanadium it is done

Comment: Great. Your old config data of 18.04 may be the issue. It is better to move just the user data back from an old home. You can test creating a new user (Settings - User). When you log in to the new user account, nautilus will start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you moved over your old home of Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, and apparently by hand, it might be that your old user configuration data, i.e., the hidden files, do not play well with Ubuntu 20.04. You can test that by (temporarily) creating a new user account. Very likely, the new account will not have the issue.

If this way, you have confirmed that the user configuration data is the problem, then you can try resetting your main account [as indicated here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43584/how-to-reset-main-user-account). Before proceeding, to be on the safe side and keep having a working account, you can give administrator privileges to the temporary user you have created. Instead of having to boot into a recovery prompt, you can use the account of your temporary new user to do this.

If, after the procedure, you succeed to log in into your current account, you can move the user data (Documents, Pictures, ...) back. Once everything is in place, the temporary account can be removed again and the `/home/youruser-backup` folder can be deleted.